# How do I archive all notes?

Tags: google-keep

How do I archive all my notes without selecting each one individually? I have hundreds (maybe thousands) of notes.

My *Reminders* page is impossible to navigate, I can't see my latest reminders without scrolling down all my notes.

I use keep mainly for reminders. When I see the notification pop up (Android), I swipe it out instead of clicking archive, so my notes are never archived. I am too lazy to do any more swiping to explicitly archive it, so it probably won't happen.

EDIT: I also want to mark all my reminders as done, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do it at the moment: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32713405?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To archive all your Keep notes at once, follow these steps:

1. Open Keep on your computer.
2. Click in a blank space on the page (not on a note).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
4. Click on the *Archive* icon at the top.